# jquery get value of dataset not working

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to get the value of my data-userid but it's not working.

Button: 
     id }}" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal-delete"> DELETE
Code:

```
$('.delete-btn').click(function(){
    userId = $(this).dataset.userId;
    alert(userId);
});
```

But attr is working.

```
 $('.delete-btn').click(function(){
    userId = $(this).attr('data-userid');
    alert(userId);
});
```

Comment: use `$(this).data('userid');`

Comment: what only that? hahaha ty. is that an update? or what? ty so much

Comment: dataset is javascript, not jquery, so `this.dataset.userid` would also work

Comment: Where is the HTML code?  `$(this).attr('data-userid')` should work if your delete button has an attribute `data-userid`.

Comment: [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/guradio/zegLxv46/) see demo but if you use `.data('userid','6')` to set the data using `.attr()` wont work because it is saved in a different location. you need to use `.data()` if you set the userId by `.data()`

Answer (score 2):

Here `$(this)` is a jQuery object , `dataset` is the property of dom object so just use `this` instead

```
$('.delete-btn').click(function(){
    userId = this.dataset.userId;
    alert(userId);
});
```

Or use **[`data()`](https://api.jquery.com/data/)** method

```
$('.delete-btn').click(function(){
    userId = $(this).data('userId');
    alert(userId);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.delete-btn').click(function(){
userId = $(this).data('userid');
alert(userId);
});
```